# Java 11 with Powermock - Are they compatible?

Tags: java, powermock, java-11, maven-surefire-plugin

After switching to Java 11, all the powermock related tests (annotated with `@RunWith(PowermockRunner.class)` and `@PowerMockIgnore`) are failing.

Is this known issue? I read a relevant SO post which was posted a year ago, and the latest release of Powermock was 2 months ago. I don't see any difference in behaviour with JDK 11.

Comment: define failing..failing with stack trace? failing in assertion?

Comment: @Naman no need to go that far. Failing during setup(). As I mentioned above, the very presence of those annotations are not working anymore - throwing IllegalAccessError and IllegalStateException. Since the reflection is now accessing internal packages. I removed `@RunWith `and `@PowerMockIgnore` from test classes - and they started running

Comment: I've tried to used PowerMock for mocking static methods of system class (java.time.LocalDate) and I've got the following exception for Java11: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 

Mockito cannot mock this class: class replica.java.time.LocalDate$$PowerMock0.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

For better clarity, it would be great if you could specify the powermock API version, what i can think of the probable clause of the exception would be PowerMock classloader reloads XML11Configuration but without specifying module/or ignore module of the class. As result the unnamed module is autogenerated.
I can suggest another workaround. If it works then my guess is correct. Could you try to 
use this option @PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.parsers.*",, "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*"})

It should work.

Comment: I think you've missed my comment above. Powermock does't work in Java 11 because "spying" and "mocking" involves private access to a lot of classes. You cannot do this using `--illegal-access=permit` with surefire plugin. Also, all the annotations you are talking about, I have already tried that, and it didn't ignore the illegal access issue. I mentioned this in the comment and yes - it's the latest API release from Oct - 2019 I think it's in 2.0.4?

Answer (score 1):

1. The existing "mvn hpi:run" command will not work correctly on Java
   11 unless Java modules are downloaded and passed to the environment.
2. List item If you use Mockito/PowerMock in your plugin tests, you may need to update to the recent versions with Java 11 support-
3. You may also need to add test annotations to workaround PowerMock
   [Issue #864](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/864). Example for the Jenkins Core

Answer (score 0):

Adding byte buddy dependency helped me to run PowerMock tests in java 14.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above PowerMock reflection access internal packages java.xml/jdk.xml, a workaround consist in allowing access to those internal packages :
if you are using maven to build your project you should add the JVM argument :

```
--add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
```

for example :

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                 <argLine>--add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If use reflect in JDK11, you might see some warning like 'An illegal reflective access operation has occurred', because reflect JDK inner API is illegal since JDK9, still you can use it with a warning above.

To fix the problem temporary, try to use `--add-exports` or `--add-opens` in your argLing.

For example: `--add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED`

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>
      @{argLine} --add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED 
    </argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For more infomation, watch [--add-opens introduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-12F945EB-71D6-46AF-8C3D-D354FD0B1781)